# Retrive environment variable value from code in mac OS

Tags: java, macos, jboss, environment-variables, system-properties

I set an Environment Variable from a .sh file for example

```
export JBOSS_HOME=/Applications/EAP-6.2.0/jboss-eap-6.2
```

Now in my Java application if I need to get this JBOSS_HOME I will write

`String jbossHome = System.getProperty("JBOSS_HOME");`

This works fine when I run the code on the windows machine.
It does not give the value for JBOSS_HOME on Mac machine.
How can I retrive JBOSS_HOME value on Mac OS machine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Environments are retrieved via:

```
System.getenv(name);
```

Not with `System.getProperty()`.

Use `System.getenv()` without paramters to get the map of all environment variables.

Comment: I am not able to get with System.getenv(name);

Comment: What do you get by calling `System.getenv("JBOSS_HOME")`?

Comment: I am writing String jbossHome = System.getenv("JBOSS_HOME");
So I am getting jbossHome as null.

Comment: This means your `JBOSS_HOME` environment variable is not global, or maybe it has been set after the launch of your Java app. Query all the environments with `System.getenv()` and display them to see what is visible to your app.